# Creating a nav bar menu without changing the element order?

Tags: html, css

How do I style this markup:

```
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
</ul>
```

into an inline menu (nav bar) that looks like the below, the first element on the left, the remaining to the right.

```
A                   B C D
```

WITHOUT CHANGING THE ORDER OF THE ELEMENTS. Can it be done? Thanks.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar can basically do what your asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one It will help you.

```css
   ul
{
text-align:right;
}
ul li:first-child{
  float:left;
}

ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like This?

```css
ul{
  text-align: right;
}

ul li:first-child{
  float:left;
}

ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
  <li>F</li>
  <li>G</li>
  <li>H</li>
  <li>J</li>
  <li>K</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

give your first li element a class, say first.

display ul li inline-block

style li.first to be wider than the rest

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:first-child` pseudo selector to target the first `li`.

Use the style:

```
li{
    display: inline;
}
li:first-child{
    margin-right: 40px;
}
```

Explanation: It will only select the `first li` and will apply `margin-right` to it, thus displacing the others to right and keeping it to the left.

See the fiddle: "http://jsfiddle.net/1b2d4qr9/"

Answer (score 1):

Yes this would work in a Nav structure the first item would float left while the the others will align on the far right side of the Nav

```
ul{padding:0;margin:0;width:100%;list-style:none;text-align:right;}
ul li:first-child{
    float:left;
}
li{display:inline-block;padding;0;margin:0;}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/Lr3bjwra/

Comment: Please try to be focused on purpose only, don't need to include extra attributes :) e.g no need to include `padding:0;margin:0;width:100%;list-style:none;`